# What the default unit in QGIS 2.18 $area is calculated and etc?

Tags: qgis, area, slope

I'm a beginner  in QGIS . We are using 2.18 version.

What are the basic units for area and slope, etc? SI, so means m, m^2, °? Or I can set it by myself? If it's possible to set it, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your your data or project. It will be the units of your data e.g. if your data is projected, then it will probably be in metres. If it is a geographic reference system such as WGS84, then it will be in decimal degrees.